# php pdo - fetch the images from mysql using path

Tags: php, mysql, image, pdo

Here i'm trying to fetch the image from database using path. Images are moved to the particular folder succesfully. You can see the coding in mainpage.php. it didn't show any error message and didn't fetch the images too.. how to fetch the images from db using path?

**mainpage.php**

```
 <?php
include "config.php";

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

try
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM testblob");
    $stmt->errorInfo();
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch())
      {
        if(file_exists("images/" . $row['image_name']))
        {
          echo '<img width=160 height=180 src="images/' . $row['image_name'] . '"/>'; 
          print_r($row['image_name']);
        }
      }
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    'Error : ' .$e->getMessage();
}
?>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="post.php" method="post" name="changer">
    <input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
    <input value="Submit" type="submit">
    </form>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php

  include 'config.php';

  if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0)
  {
     echo "<font size = '5'><font>Error<br />";
     echo"<font size = '5'><font>inserted";
   }
   else
   {
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
     echo"<font size = '5'><font color=\"#0CF44A\">SAVED<br>";

    try
    {   
        $file="images/".$_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO testblob (image_name) VALUES (:file)");
        $stmt->errorInfo();
        $stmt->bindParam(':file', $file, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $stmt->execute();    
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        'Error : ' .$e->getMessage();
    }

     if(!$stmt)
     {
        die('Error');
     }
     echo "<font size = '5'><font>saved to db";

   }

?>
```

Comment: Does the httpd account have permission to read the 'images' folder?

Comment: @ethrbunny : honestly i don't know about that. How to check that?

Comment: Depending on the OS you could either use sudo or file/properties.. or just cut all that and look at the server logs.